# Herencia en c++. se debe crear la clase hija y la clase padre?

Tags: c++

Como es que funciona la herencia en c++?

aqui tengo un ejemplo: lo pueden ver en mi git https://github.com/hubmanS/plusDemo

```
Div::Div(string nameDiv, vector<std::string> attrDiv):Doom(Div::name, Div::attr)
{
    name=nameDiv;
    attr=attrDiv;
    cout<<"DIV"<<endl;
}
```

para crear herencia debo crear la clase hija y la clase padre?
es necesario crear la clase padre?

este es el file .h

```
class Div:public Doom
{
public:
    Div(string, vector<std::string>);
    string addPropertie(string );
    vector<std::string> attr;
    string name;
};
```

.h Doom

```
class Doom
{
public:
    Doom(std::string,  vector<std::string>  );
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con eso de "*¿Cómo es que funciona la herencia?*"?

Comment: @eferion para crear herencia estoy usando esto Div::Div(string nameDiv, vector<std::string> attrDiv):Doom(Div::name, Div::attr), por que debo crear el padre Doom si es abstracto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> para crear herencia debo crear la clase hija y la clase padre?

Aquí te estás refiriendo a esta sección del código:

```
Div::Div(string nameDiv, vector<std::string> attrDiv):Doom(Div::name, Div::attr)
```

Y, efectivamente, para crear la clase hija se **debe invocar el constructor** de la clase padre. ¿Por qué? Pues porque resulta que la clase padre puede tener variables privadas así como sus propias herencias. Para que un objeto de la clase derivada esté correctamente inicializado es necesario que **todos sus elementos** lo estén. Y claro, con **todos sus elementos** no nos referimos solo a las variables miembros declaradas directamente en la clase derivada, sino también las correspondientes a todas las clases padre de las que herede.

Si no se usase este modelo sería necesario, a la hora de crear una clase derivada, conocer con total precisión todas y cada una de sus herencias (de primer nivel, de segundo, ...) para poder inicializar correctamente su estado... claro que esto entraría en conflicto con los conceptos de aislamiento y encapsulamiento...

> por que debo crear el padre Doom si es abstracto?

Una cosa es que una clase sea abstracta y otra que no tenga estado. Una clase abstracta es simplemente una clase que tiene al menos un método virtual sin implementar. Debido a esto nos va a resultar imposible crear objetos de este tipo porque ese método no se puede quedar sin implementación.

Sin embargo la clase abstracta puede tener declaradas variables e incluso puede tener herencias. Todos esos elementos deben inicializarse, como he comentado antes, y de ahí que sea necesario invocar a los constructores en cascada.

> en java uso la palabra reservada super() y con eso obtenia las caracteristicas del padre

Estás mezclando churras con merinas. En java tienes `super()` simplemente porque **no admite herencia múltiple**. Es decir, puedes heredar de varias interfaces pero únicamente de una clase... mientras que en C++ no tiene tal restricción.

Así, con `super()` no hay ambigüedad alguna y el compilador sabe que te refieres a la clase padre... en Java. ¿Y en C++? Está claro que en el caso del ejemplo todos *vemos* que la herencia es de cajón:

```
struct A
{
  A(int a)
  { /* ... */ };
};

struct B : A
{
  B(float a, int b)
    : A(b) // Nos referimos a la clase padre A... no hay otra posibilidad!!!
  { /* ... */ }
};
```

Pero no hay que olvidar que C++ no se diseñó con este caso de uso en mente sino con otros más ilustrativos:

```
struct A
{
  A(int a)
  { /* ... */ };
};

struct B
{
  B(int a)
  { /* ... */ }
};

struct C : A, B
{
  C(int a, int b)
    : /* ¿? */
  { }
}
```

¿Cómo resolvemos este caso? Está claro que con `super()` no podríamos porque, ¿Cómo lo hacemos? ¿Usamos dos veces esa palabra reservada? ¿Y entonces a qué constructor estamos invocando exactamente la primera vez?

Así que en C++ no existen azucarillos para invocar a los constructores de las clases padre... estos han de ser explícitos. Si no se indica un constructor entonces se invocará el constructor por defecto (el cual debe existir o se generará un error en tiempo de compilación).

```
struct A
{
  A(){ std::cout << "Hola\n"; }
};

struct B : A
{
  // Al no indicar ningún constructor se implementara el constructor por defecto
  // que llamará al constructor por defecto de A
};

struct C : A
{
  C(int)
  { }  // Como no indicamos constructor de A, se invocara el constructor por defecto
};

struct D : C
{
  D()
  { } // Error, C no dispone de constructor por defecto
};

struct E : C
{
  E() : C(5)
  { } // OK, invocamos al constructor de C de forma explícita
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  C c(1);
  E e;
}
```

---

> que datos debo poner aqui Doom(Div::name, Div::attr)? los mismos de div?

Como puedes notar, la implementación de tu constructor es incorrecta. Viendo el código, una implementación esperable sería:

```
Div::Div(string nameDiv, vector<std::string> attrDiv) : Doom(nameDiv, attrDiv)
{ }
```

Es decir, `Div` no necesita duplicar las variables existentes en la clase padre. Luego su declaración podría parecerse más a esta:

```
class Div:public Doom
{
public:
    Div(string, vector<std::string>);
    string addPropertie(string );
};
```

Fíjate que han desaparecido las dos variables... ya están declaradas en la clase padre, luego lo lógico sería usar dichas variables en vez de duplicarlas.

Comment: que datos debo poner aqui Doom(Div::name, Div::attr)? los mismos de div?